# Creating identical page in Wordpress shows no content

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I am trying to understand the file structure of a WordPress theme. I have a user page with a URL http://example.com/user/username. I noticed that inside the active theme there is a user.php, which is probably serving this page, right? I create a new page, call it User2 using the same template as User, and a new php file named user2.php is placed in the theme. I also noticed the new row in the wp-posts table. However, when I navigate to http://example.com/user2/username, the page loads but shows no content, just header/footer/sidebar. Why?

Comment: Check here http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: Thanks for the link. So my page is a static page cause its post_type is equal to page. And wordpress first looks for a custom template file - the Page Template assigned to the page. The template I chose is called Standard template, but I cannot see a file named as such in the templates folder of the theme.

Comment: I cannot understand how the first url is served by user.php, where is this choice made?